# Check if a directory called "marked" under *.ext directory exists? and if they exists then when the last time files under "marked" were modified

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have multiple directories with ending with "`.ext`".
Some directory have sub-directory called e.g. "`abc.ext/tree/child/marked`". But not all directories have the "marked" directory under it.

(1) How to look for all directory?

Also, some directory which have "`marked`" directory aren't updated in last 1 month. Which brings to second question:

(2) How to find all marked directory which consists all files under it at least a month old.

Comment: Did you have a look at the `find` command and its options like `-name`, `-type` and `-ctime`? Can you please try for yourself and ask for assistence with your attempt? That's the best way to learn, I think.

Comment: Great advice, thank you!